# How to create good footnote in ireport?

Tags: jasper-reports, footnotes

I need to make a footnote in iReport. The description of footnote should be displayed only in the bottom(footer) of the page, where we have number-reference in text.

How we can catch the reference in text and show footnote using variables or group names? May be anyone has some examples?

Which is best-practice for footnotes?